# How to update dynamic text using innerHtml with Angular 5 and Material Design

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a list with dynamic data and I want to update a specific text when the user clicks on a button :

```html
<mat-list> 
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let id of ids">
      <mat-radio-group>
        <mat-radio-button name="car" value="honda" id="honda{{id}}" (change)="onChangeCar(id,honda)">Honda</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button name="car" value="toyota" id="toyota{{id}}" (change)="onChangeCar(id,toyota)">Toyota</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
   </mat-list-item>
<span [id]="id">Text to update</span>
</mat-list>
```

How to update the text dynamically in an Angular way? I know how to do it with the old fashion way but it's not suggested :

```ts
onChangeCar(id) {
  (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).innerHTML = "new text at a 
  specific Id";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<span [id]="id">Text to update</span>
```

with

```
<span >{{newVal}}</span>
```

and in your component create a variable to bind with newVal

Comment: i know how to do that with an explicit id, but i'm asking how to do it for a dynamic id

Comment: try this -> <span [innerHtml]="id">Text to update</span>

Comment: lol...my question is how to replace this : (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).innerHTML by an Angular 5 way !

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but you can simply add a content modifier to your element, such as:

```
<span [innerHTML]="carName"></span>
```

And in your code have update a class variable such as this:

```
public carName: string;

onChangeCar(newName) { 
   this.carName = newName;
}
```

This way, the text of the element will become whatever you set the variable `carName` has been set to.